# How to add a file from manu to a file tree in extjs 4.2?

Tags: file-browser, extjs4.2

I have created a toolbar with menu item in it:

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    padding: '30 0 0 0',
    width   : '100%',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            text : 'File',
            menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                  width: 200,
                  margin: '0 0 10 0',
                  items: [
                      {
                          text: 'Import',
                          // code here
                      }
                  ]
            })
         }
    ]
});
```

So what I am trying to do is to be able to use **Import** button just like **File->Open**.
I know that I can add **`xtype: 'filebutton'`**, but it shows the browse button with the text field.
Also I want to let the user to choose only certain file extensions. After file is selected (we click open), I want to add it to my file tree in my **`viewport`**.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using **`xtype: 'fileuploadfield'`** and hiding the file name/text field.

```
xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
buttonText : 'Open',
buttonOnly: true,
```

It is as simple as it gets. Just create a `toolbar` and have this code in its `item` field.